# How to start tmux without a status bar, and without modifying the config file?

Tags: vim, tmux

Ordinarily, I like `tmux` with its status bar.
However in vim with `:term tmux` I would like it to be started without.

Hence, keeping the same config file, can some args could be used so `tmux` starts without its status bar? It's not immediately apparent how.

E.g. `tmux set-status -g status` will not work because it expects a tmux session to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- I know your title says, *"without modifying"* the config, but then your question body says, *"keeping the same config."*  For a single `~/.tmux.conf` that will work in both cases and detect if you are running from within a Vim terminal, add the following line in your config.

  For Tmux 3.2a and later (cleaner syntax):

  ```
  if-shell '[ ! -z "$VIMRUNTIME" ]' {
      set -g status off
  }
  ```

  For older Tmux versions:

  ```
  if-shell '[ ! -z "$VIMRUNTIME" ]' "set -g status off"
  ```

  That will only turn off the status bar if you are starting Tmux in a shell where the `$VIMRUNTIME` variable is defined (e.g. `:term tmux`).
- To start Tmux from the command-line with no status-bar:

  ```
  tmux new-session\; set -g status off
  ```

  That starts the session *then* turns off the status bar, rather than the other way around.

  Reference: "Parsing Syntax" in the Tmux man page.

Comment: Works, thanks a ton!